# Aligning with epslatex terminal labels in gnuplot

Tags: latex, gnuplot, eps

Suppose I have the following minimal working example of my gnuplot (4.6.2) version.

```
set terminal epslatex size 6cm, 4cm  font "" 8 standalone
set output "test.tex"

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]

set label "$\\alpha=1\,b=0.1$" at 2,8

plot x
```

Which gives me the below output:

[image: Example]

What I now want, is to put my parameters alpha and b underneath eachother, optimally aligned at the equality sign.

I tried something like

```
set label "\\begin{eqnarray}\\alpha=1 \\\\ b=0.1\\end{eqnarray}" at 2,8
```

This does not give me errors in gnuplot, but upon compilation it fails, which an error like

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.153     \gplbacktext
```

which does not really help me any further.

Any suggestion on how to approach this issue?

Comment: For breaking text in general (as opposed to only equations) I usually use the `\shortstack{}` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach with the `eqnarray` equation would work if you would put it inside a `\parbox`. I think it's better to use the `aligned` environment of the `amsmath` package:

```
set terminal epslatex size 6cm,4cm standalone header '\usepackage{amsmath}'
set output "foobar.tex"

set xrange [0:10]

set label '$\begin{aligned}\alpha&=1\\b&=0.1\end{aligned}$' at 1,7

plot x

set output
system('latex foobar.tex && dvips foobar.dvi && ps2pdf foobar.ps')
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Yup, that works for me! I also agree with `aligned` because for the `eqnarray`, the default is to use equation-numbers

Comment: By the way, why do you add an additional `set output` at the end of the script?

Comment: You must add the `set output` to flush the output file, which is required before you can compile from inside the gnuplot script with the `system` call.

Comment: Ok, in my workflow I do the compilation outside of gnuplot in a Makefile, so I don't need it. Thanks again!